# Import documents to MediaWiki

Tags: ms-word, mediawiki

I wish to import a bunch of documents (100's) into a wiki on our company intranet ([MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki)).  Lots have embedded images as well.  Is there a way to import them (images included)?

I can't seem to find an offline MediaWiki editor. I would be willing to pay for this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is as far as I'm aware no standard software to do this.

You can try to export the word documents to HTML and if $wgRawHtml = true you can import them directly into MediaWiki.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this? I'm asking because you can end up with a lot of junk (expired information) in your wiki if you do that.

To do it manually you can use the [FCK Editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_%28Official%29) but you will still need to upload the images separately. It will takes ages but at least you can review as you go and only upload the really important stuff.

I know of someone who did what you said using a bot with the mwclient functionality - but I don't know more than that.

Comment: Please see also this wiki Q&A forum in start up phase: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wiki-edit

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion - if you decide to keep the old info in Word (as I suggested), I think you should allow wiki users to link to the documents. If they are in a decent content management system, they will all have a unique URL. You could easily create a template, containing the basic URL, with the specific document identification as a parameter.

That way, the up to date information is on the wiki and the old information is only one click away.